# How to print to a POS printer from the php server

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, printing, pos

I have a web of delivery services, where the customer places his order from the website and in the restaurant the user receives the order by means of the automatic printing of the ticket with the order. The tickets must be printed automatically in the restarant after the customer makes the order. In localhost using XAMPP I can print the ticket well but the problem is how to print from the hosting.

I created this next code that I run using a CRON Job but so far the tickets do not print. I execute this Cron every 1 minute. I also have the printer configured on the computer enabling the shared printer option.

This is the code for cron job:

```
      include_once "../../../app/config.inc.php";
              include_once "../../../app/Connection.php";

              class PrintTickets
              {

              public static function CheckOrderToPrint ($connection, $status) 
              {
                    $category = [];

                    if (isset($connection)) {
                      try {

                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status =:status ORDER BY id ASC";
                        $sentence = $connection ->prepare($sql);
                        $sentence -> bindParam (':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $sentence -> execute();
                        $result = $sentence -> fetch();

                    if (!empty($result)) {
                        $category = [$result['id'], 
                                    $result['id_preOrder'],
                                    $result['total_amount'], 
                                    $result['discount'],
                                    $result['liefergenbuhr'],
                                    $result['gesamtbetrag'],
                                    $result['order_number'],
                                    $result['status']];
                         }
                      } catch (PDOException $ex) {

                        print 'ERROR' . $ex -> getMessage();
                      }
                    }
                  return $category;
                }




                public static function CheckPreOrderToPrint ($connection, $id) 
              {
                  $category = [];

                    if (isset($connection)) {
                      try {

                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM pre_order WHERE id =:id";
                        $sentence = $connection ->prepare($sql);
                        $sentence -> bindParam (':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $sentence -> execute();
                        $result = $sentence -> fetch();

                    if (!empty($result)) {
                        $category = [$result['id'], 
                                    $result['order_num'],
                                    $result['address'], 
                                    $result['zip_code'],
                                    $result['other_field'],
                                    $result['type_order'],
                                    $result['status']];
                         }
                      } catch (PDOException $ex) {

                        print 'ERROR' . $ex -> getMessage();
                      }
                    }
                  return $category;
                }


                public static function CheckOrderDetailsToPrint($connection, $id) 
                  {
                  $category = [];
                    if (isset($connection)) {
                      try {
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE id_order = :id_order";
                        $sentence = $connection ->prepare($sql);
                        $sentence -> bindParam (':id_order', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $sentence -> execute();
                        $result = $sentence -> fetchAll();

                    if (count($result)) {
                        foreach ($result as $row) 
                          {
                            $category[] = [$row['id'], $row['id_order'], $row['id_dish'], $row['quantity']];
                          } 
                        }
                      } catch (PDOException $ex) {

                        print 'ERROR' . $ex -> getMessage();
                      }
                    }
                  return $category;
                }


               public static function CheckOrderDishesToPrint($connection, $id) 
                  {
                  $category = [];
                    if (isset($connection)) {
                      try {
                        $sql = "SELECT p.*, c.name AS category FROM products p INNER JOIN category c ON p.id_category = c.id WHERE p.id = :id";
                        $sentence = $connection ->prepare($sql);
                        $sentence -> bindParam (':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $sentence -> execute();
                        $result = $sentence -> fetch();

                    if (!empty($result)) {
                        //foreach ($result as $row) {
                            $category[] = [$result['id'], 
                                    $result['id_category'],
                                    $result['name'], 
                                    $result['ingredients'],
                                    $result['price'],
                                    $result['status'],
                                    $result['category']];
                          //}
                         }
                      } catch (PDOException $ex) {

                        print 'ERROR' . $ex -> getMessage();
                      }
                    }
                  return $category;
                }


                 public static function UpdateOrdersPrint ($connection, $id, $status) {
                   $preOrder_saved = false;
                   $lastId = 0;
                  if (isset($connection)) {

                    try {
                      $sql = "UPDATE orders SET status = :status WHERE id = :id"; 
                      $sentence = $connection -> prepare($sql);
                      $sentence -> bindParam (':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                      $sentence -> bindParam (':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                      $preOrder_saved = $sentence -> execute();
                      $lastId = $connection->lastInsertId(); 

                    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
                      print 'ERROR' . $ex -> getMessage();
                    }
                  }
                  return $lastId;
                }



                public static function GlobalGetGeneral($connection, $id) 
                {
                    $orders = null;
                    if (isset($connection)) {
                      try {
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM global_setting WHERE id = :id";
                        $sentence = $connection ->prepare($sql);
                         $sentence -> bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $sentence -> execute();
                        $result = $sentence -> fetch();

                    if (!empty($result)) 
                       {
                        $orders = [$result['id'], $result['discount'], $result['rest_name'], $result['coin'], $result['address'], $result['phone'], $result['email']];
                         }
                      } catch (PDOException $ex) {

                        print 'ERROR' . $ex -> getMessage();
                      }
                    }
                  return $orders;
                }



                public static function GetCustomerOrders($connection, $pre_order_Id) {
                   $orders = null;
                    if (isset($connection)) {
                      try {
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM costumers WHERE pre_order_Id = :pre_order_Id";
                        $sentence = $connection ->prepare($sql);
                        $sentence -> bindParam(':pre_order_Id', $pre_order_Id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $sentence -> execute();
                        $result = $sentence -> fetch();

                    if (!empty($result)) 
                       {
                        $orders = [$result['id'], $result['first_name'], $result['last_name'], $result['firma'], $result['address'], $result['zip_code'], $result['zip_code2'], $result['zip_address'], $result['telephone'], $result['email'], $result['etage'], $result['nachricht'], $result['pre_order_Id']];
                         }
                      } catch (PDOException $ex) {

                        print 'ERROR' . $ex -> getMessage();
                      }
                    }
                  return $orders;
                }

              }


                    Connection::open_db();
                    $status = "Processed";
                    $poststatus = "Finished";

                    $Result = PrintTickets::CheckOrderToPrint(Connection::GetConnection(), $status);
                    if($Result)
                    {

                    $orderNum = $Result[0];

                    $Result2 = PrintTickets::GlobalGetGeneral(Connection::GetConnection(), 1);
                    $restaurent = $Result2[2];
                    $adresse = $Result2[4];
                    $celphone = $Result2[5];
                    $email = $Result2[6];
                    $coin = $Result2[3];
                    $IDRest = "YG84784FOSJD-00";  

                    $Result3 = PrintTickets::GetCustomerOrders(Connection::GetConnection(), $Result[1]);

                    $name = $Result3[1] ." ". $Result3[2];
                    $telefone = $Result3[8];
                    $emailCos = $Result3[9];
                    $ID_Client = $Result3[10]; 

                    $Result4 = PrintTickets::CheckPreOrderToPrint(Connection::GetConnection(), $Result[1]); 

                    $type_orders = $Result4[5];

                    if ($type_orders == "TAKE_OVER") 
                    {
                      $type_orders = "TAKE OVER";
                    }
                    else if ($type_orders == "DELIVERY")
                    {
                      $type_orders = "DELIVERY";
                    }

                    $dish_details = "";

                    $Result6 = PrintTickets::CheckOrderDetailsToPrint(Connection::GetConnection(), $Result[0]);

                    //
                    //print_r($Result6);

                   $total = $Result[2]; 
                   for ($i=0; $i < count($Result6); $i++) 
                    { 
                      $price = 0;
                      $Result5 = PrintTickets::CheckOrderDishesToPrint(Connection::GetConnection(), $Result6[$i][2]);
                      //print_r($Result5);
                      for ($j=0; $j < $Result6[$i][3]; $j++) 
                      { 
                        $price = ($price + $Result5[0][4]);
                      }

                      $dish_details = $dish_details . "<tr><td>".$Result6[$i][3]."</td><td>".$Result5[0][6]. " " . $Result5[0][2]."</td><td align='right'>".$price."</td></tr>";
                    }

                    include_once "windows-usb.php";

                    $Result7 = PrintTickets::UpdateOrdersPrint(Connection::GetConnection(), $Result[0], $poststatus);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                    echo "nothing yet";
                    }

                    Connection::close_db();
```

and this is the windows-usb.php file:

```
     /* Change to the correct path if you copy this example! */
                require __DIR__ . '/../../autoload.php';
                use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
                use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;

                /**
                 * Install the printer using USB printing support, and the "Generic / Text Only" driver,
                 * then share it (you can use a firewall so that it can only be seen locally).
                 *
                 * Use a WindowsPrintConnector with the share name to print.
                 *
                 * Troubleshooting: Fire up a command prompt, and ensure that (if your printer is shared as
                 * "Receipt Printer), the following commands work:
                 *
                 *  echo "Hello World" > testfile
                 *  copy testfile "\\%COMPUTERNAME%\Receipt Printer"
                 *  del testfile
                 */
                try {
                    // Enter the share name for your USB printer here
                    //$connector = null;
                    $connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("HP Photosmart C4400 series2");

                    /* Print a "Hello world" receipt" */

                    $printer = new Printer($connector);

                    $printer -> text("<table border='0' align='center' width='385px'><tr><td align='center'>.::<strong> ". $restaurent ." </strong>::.\n ". $celphone ." - ID: ". $IDRest ."</td></tr><tr><td align='center'>Date/Time:" . date('d-m-Y H:i:s') . "</td></tr><tr><td align='left'></td></tr><tr><td>Client: ".$name."</td></tr><tr><td>ID Client: ".$ID_Client."</td></tr><tr><td>Order Nº: ".$orderNum."</td></tr><tr><td colspan='3' align='left'>Type of Order: ".$type_orders."</td></tr></table>\n"."<table border='0' align='center' width='300px'><tr><td><span id='cantDragg'>QUANTITY.</span></td><td><span id='descripDragg'>DETAILS</span></td><td align='right'><span id='importDragg'>TOTAL</span></td></tr><tr><td colspan='3'>==========================================</td></tr>"."<tr><td>Here Quantity</td><td>Here Dish Name</td><td align='right'>Here price</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>Pizza 4 cheese</td><td align='right'>330 CHF</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td align='right'><b>TOTAL:</b></td><td align='right'><b>360 CHF</b></td></tr><tr><td colspan='3'>Nº of Dishes: 2</td></tr><tr><td colspan='3'>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td colspan='3' align='center'>here other important detail</td></tr></table>");
                    $printer -> cut();
                    /* Close printer */
                    $printer -> close();
                    //header("Location:../../../../index.php");



                    echo "<table border='0' align='center' width='385px'><tr><td align='center'>.::<strong> ". $restaurent ." </strong>::. \n". $celphone ." - ID: ". $IDRest ."</td></tr><tr><td align='center'>Date/Time:" . date('d-m-Y H:i:s') . "</td></tr><tr><td align='left'></td></tr><tr><td>Client: ".$name."</td></tr><tr><td>ID Client: ".$ID_Client."</td></tr><tr><td>Order Nº: ".$orderNum."</td></tr><tr><td colspan='3' align='left'>Type of Order: ".$type_orders."</td></tr></table>\n"."<table border='0' align='center' width='300px'><tr><td><span id='cantDragg'>QUANTITY.</span></td><td><span id='descripDragg'>DETAILS</span></td><td align='right'><span id='importDragg'>TOTAL</span></td></tr><tr><td colspan='3'>==========================================</td></tr>". $dish_details."<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td align='right'><b>TOTAL:</b></td><td align='right'><b>".$total." ".$coin."</b></td></tr><tr><td colspan='3'>Nº of Dishes: 2</td></tr><tr><td colspan='3'>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td colspan='3' align='center'>here other important detail</td></tr></table>";


                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    echo "Couldn't print to this printer: " . $e -> getMessage() . "\n";
                }
```

How can I do to print the tickets automatically from the hosting after client make the order?
I use the ESC/POS Library to make the printing 
easier. All the folders and files of the library are well located in the server folder where the system are located.

This delivery page also has its content management system, which also has a menu that shows the orders made by customers. This is where the folder with the ESC / POS library is located and the php file to print with cron is also there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your printer in not connected to server, so you can't control printer from server.

There are several ways to do that.

1. The method by google cloud print
   I could succeed in printing from server to local pos printer with using cloud printer.
   I've registered my printer into cloud printer, and converted receipt to pdf, but the 
   printed result was not good.
   So, I don't recommend this method.
2. The method with using local network.
   You can set up printer in your wifi network that connected your client browser.
   For printing, in your client browser, will send request to your local printer.
   it works well and I am using for that.
   In the case of wifi-printer, you have to have laptop.
   And also you can use raspberry pi to reduce the size and dedicated service for 
   printing.
3. The method by vps.
   Someone says that we can get dedicated public ip from vps service.
   But I could not configure that yet.
   But I think it can be a good way also.